# PyStan example program plot not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stan

In trying the Stan 8 school example program the output is not plotting when using fit.plot(). 
https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

I've installed matplotlib and the examples they provide plot. 
I'm running it from macOS iterm.

Answer (score 0):

It was missing plt.show().
I've pasted the full code below.

```
import pystan
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

schools_code = """
data {
    int<lower=0> J; // number of schools
    real y[J]; // estimated treatment effects
    real<lower=0> sigma[J]; // s.e. of effect estimates
}
parameters {
    real mu;
    real<lower=0> tau;
    real eta[J];
}
transformed parameters {
    real theta[J];
    for (j in 1:J)
    theta[j] = mu + tau * eta[j];
}
model {
    eta ~ normal(0, 1);
    y ~ normal(theta, sigma);
}
"""

schools_dat = {'J': 8,
               'y': [28,  8, -3,  7, -1,  1, 18, 12],
               'sigma': [15, 10, 16, 11,  9, 11, 10, 18]}

sm = pystan.StanModel(model_code=schools_code)
fit = sm.sampling(data=schools_dat, iter=1000, chains=4)
print(fit)
fit.plot()

plt.show()
```